# ASUS laptop FX503: Keyboard backlight control not work in Linux

Tags: linux-device-driver, asus

The laptop is ASUS FX503vd,  I tried several versions of Linux kernels (currently running one is the 4.17.1), but still have not managed to make the keyboard backlight control keys work. After the system boot on, the backlight is always on.  There are two function keys (reused the numerical keypad) which is to control the brightness of the backlight.  In windows, I can adjust down its brightness until fully off.  But pressing the same keys in Linux has no effect at all.  My feeling is the kernel did not detected the corresponding WMI device

Below is the /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/ contents:

> ~ $ ls /sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/
>
> cpufv    driver_override  input/    power/      uevent
>
> driver@  hwmon/           modalias  subsystem@

And, below is the kernel message filtered by 'asus' keyword: (i.e. dmesg |grep 'asus')

> [    6.698065] asus_wmi: ASUS WMI generic driver loaded
>
> [    6.700669] asus_wmi: Initialization: 0x1
>
> [    6.700723] asus_wmi: BIOS WMI version: 8.1
>
> [    6.700764] asus_wmi: SFUN value: 0x4a0061
>
> [    6.701323] input: Asus WMI hotkeys as /devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input10
>
> [    6.703080] asus_wmi: Number of fans: 1

Does anyone have some clues about the laptop keyboard issue?

Does the driver depend on the layout of the keyboard?

Thanks in advance.
-woody

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be a *programming* one, thus **off-topic** on Stack Overflow. You may try to ask it on [su].

Comment: Now I found the asus-laptop module cannot be loaded: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'asus_laptop': No such device

Comment: @WoodyWu were you able to resolve this issue ? I have the same Asus laptop and facing the exact same issue with this laptop. I have searched a lot on internet in search of a solution but nothing yet. Were you able to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is guid in kernel Documentation in [Documentation/laptops/asus-laptop.txt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5924bbecd0267d87c24110cbe2041b5075173a25/Documentation/laptops/asus-laptop.txt).

According to that follow the steps to enable this functionality.

1. modprobe asus-laptop (check dmesg)
2. You can control lcd backlight power and brightness with
   /sys/class/backlight/asus-laptop/. Brightness Values are between 0 and 15.

Comment: The asus-laptop cannot be loaded: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'asus_laptop': No such device.   I think for this reason I have no /sys/class/backlight/asus-laptop directory.

Comment: if you can compile custom kernel select "Asus Laptop Extras" config ASUS_LAPTOP then try it in new kernel image and modprobe asus-laptop

Answer (score 0):

I hope you did it somehow but for those who didn't managed to do it, there is a little advice

!!! This works only on ubuntu based distros !!!

You will probably have to install newer kernel (which is not in repository for everyone to install). That may help you with much more problems like backlight issues or so.

You can look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1044402/838278). There is written how to update your current kernel. kernel versions are not up to date so you'll have to choose some higher version.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: is it all versions of ubuntu based distros?

Comment: What do you mean ?
You can download and install ANY version of kernel on a distro of your choice :)

Comment: Sorry for later replying. I want to report that after upgraded my ubuntu get upgraded automatically, the issue disappeared. It made me believe it's a kernel incompatibility issue. The ubuntu I am now using is 19.03, but it's the version previous to this one that already worked.